# unable to login to a website (which uses JWT tokens) through jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jwt, token, correlation

website is made using reactJS and it uses JWT tokens to enhance security.I have recorded the login and logout scenario using Jmeter. Jmeter has captured the username as it is but password is encrypted when i replaced the password with real password, login failed, I really don't know how else can i log in to that application

Answer (score 0):

If JMeter recorded password as "encrypted" it's being encrypted in the browser by [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) so if you want to use plain text "real" password in your test you will need to implement the same password encryption logic as your application does using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Once you perform the login you should get a [JWT token](https://jwt.io/) which will be used as the proof that you're authorized, it can be extracted using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), stored into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and used in the subsequent requests.